# Setting host/remote_addr and other env properties in Rails 3 controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, controller

In Rails 2, you could specify the host and other Rack env properties in controller tests like so:

```
should "spoof host and remote_addr" do
  get "/thing/2", {}, :remote_addr => "192.71.1.2", :host => "somewhere.else"
end
```

However, for some reason this is not working out on Rails 3. I tried with a regular controller, and `env["HTTP_HOST"]` isn't being set as expected (same with `"REMOTE_ADDR"`). I also tried this:

```
should "use host and remote_addr" do
  request.env["REMOTE_ADDR"] = "192.71.1.2"
  request.env["HTTP_HOST"] = "git.gittit.it"
  get "/thing/1"
end
```

This also used to work in Rails 2, but no longer in Rails 3. As a final test, I tried this with a route that resolved to a bare Rack app, same results.

How can I spoof the host and IP address in a Rails 3 controller test?

Comment: My use-case for this was a Rack app. I eventually gave up and instead do this in my tests: `MyRackEndPoint.call({ "PATH_INFO" => "/hey", "HTTP_HOST" => "myhost.com" })` which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're accessing it in the controller... this has worked well for me:

```
request.stub!(:remote_ip).and_return('192.71.1.2')
```

At which point when I use `request.remote_ip` in my controller, I get 192.71.1.2

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for something less fragile. I just want to transport data from A to B, stubbing should be unnecessary. Also, this own't work for Metals/Rack apps.